# Laravel Gate resource with policy not existing

Tags: laravel, resources, policy

I am trying to implement Policies in my project and I have a custom method `askFriend` that I want to add to my `UserRelationPolicy`.

So I implemented in my UserRelationPolicy the askFriend method but when trying to call it from the `UserRelationPolicy@askFriend` I asked myself how to call it from this method.

Something like `$this->authorize('askFriend', $friend);` but it was not working, kind of ignoring it at all. So I searched further in the documentation and found that I could bind with a Gate method the specific method in the `UserRelationPolicy` to a resource name like this :

```
Gate::resource('userrelation', 'UserRelationPolicy', [
    'userrelation.askfriendrelation' => 'askFriendRelation'
]);
```

You can find the representation here : [Documentation Writing Gate](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization#writing-gates)

When I try to execute this code I get the following error :

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\Access\Gate::resource()
```

And nothing more. The Resource method doesn't seem to exist at all. After many search, trying to include every `Gate` in the header. Trying to call it staticly or with an instance. Nothing work and the method is nowhere near to be found...

Is it something forgotten ? How can I call a custom method from a controller in a policy class ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using 5.4? The method Gate::resource was implemented only in 5.4.
If you are using any version behind you will have to use the `Gate::define`.

Set the Gate abilities in the `App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider` like this:

```
Gate::define('userrelation.askfriendrelation', 'UserRelationPolicy@askFriend');
```

Comment: The command `php artisan -v` gives me the following result `Laravel Framework 5.4.18` So I think I'm at the right version but I don't find the method...

Comment: Check the Gate class at `Illuminate\Auth\Access\Gate.php`  and compare to this one: `https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Auth/Access/Gate.php`. If has any difference in the code, you should double check your composer.json and run `composer update`.

Comment: I got the same error today, i ran `compose update`, updated to 5.4.24 and the problem was solved. Take a chance.